# Why is my button not working when i click the top few pixels

Tags: css

I've made a stackblitz for you to understand my problem.
I think it has something to do with my css for buttons...

Basically when you hit the button at the very top few pixels the state will not switch aka it doesn't detect a click

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qiq87e

Comment: whats wrong can you just explain your problem here.the link shows button is working fine and show state true or false

Comment: provide the code .

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama corrected the link

Comment: @HaSnenTai Try clicking the button at the very top

Comment: I tried clicking everywhere and it's working normally

Comment: @HaSnenTai Nope. The top portion fails.

Comment: Could this problem only occur in certain browsers?

Comment: which browser you are using and try removing the class and check weather i behaves the same ?

Comment: @HaSnenTai Firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove this css style and it will work perfect .

```
button:active {
    /* margin-top: 1%; */ //remove it
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 5px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 5px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 5px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to still have that visual effect then?

Comment: lemme check for it . @niehoelzz

Comment: Found anything?

Comment: Working on it . @niehoelzz

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought you would have given up by now. Really appreciate your effort!

Comment: Thank you . Happy to help you . @niehoelzz